# How to add 2 params from form to URL using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with 2 selects:

```
  <form class="config-form" action="https://myapp.net/order" method="GET">
    <div class="config-inner">
        <select id="from" value="from" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="on">
            <option value="122">Spanish</option>
        </select>
        <select id="to" value="to" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="on">
            <option value="133">Arabic</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="" id="configsubmit" class="create-button" tabindex="0">Empezar</button>
    </div>
   </form>
```

I need to add the selected values to the URL as 2 params, so I get this URL:
https://myapp.com/order?from=selectvalue1&to=selectvalue2

How I can proceed?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why JavaScript/jQuery at all? Just replace `value` with `name` in the `<select>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andreas suggested setting the `name` attribute of the select tags does the trick. You don't need Javascript or jQuery for this.

```html
<form class="config-form" action="https://myapp.net/order" method="GET">
    <div class="config-inner">
        <select id="from" name="from" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="on">
            <option value="122">Spanish</option>
        </select>
        <select id="to" name="to" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="on">
            <option value="133">Arabic</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="" id="configsubmit" class="create-button" tabindex="0">Empezar</button>
    </div>
   </form>
```

... or if you don't want to submit the page please elaborate a bit.